# woocommerce: how to get products with certain attribute of certain value

Tags: wordpress, attributes, woocommerce, product, taxonomy

I have created a custom attribute in my woocommerce site called `future_availability_qty`
Now I need to be able to list all products that have a `future_availability_qty` greater than 5.

How can I retrieve all products that have a `future_availability_qty` greater than 5?

Comment: How did you create this custom attribute?

Comment: via admin->products->attributes

Answer (score 1):

Like querying for just about anything else in WordPress, you should consider using a standard [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

You know a few things:

1. You are only interested in products (post type `product`)
2. The custom attribute is called `future_availability_qty` (`meta_key`)
3. The attribute value should be `> 5` (`meta_value_num`)

The query may look something like the following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'future_availability_qty',
    'meta_value_num' => 5,
    'meta_compare' => '>'
);
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Read more about custom field parameters [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Comment: thanks.  it somewhat got what i wanted...i wanted the product display information such as name of product, availabilty etc..

Comment: That's not what you asked in your original question (and is a completely different question). I recommend asking a different one, if you're still looking for a solution.